# How to return 2 models in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 2 models that I want to render to my html code and I tried doing this:

```
    form = CreateNewList()
    empName = employeeName.objects.all
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form":form}, {"empName":empName})
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateNewList(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateNewList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget = TextInput()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
```

but it does not work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is `CreateNewList()` ? Also, you need parentheses like that `employeeName.objects.all()`.

Comment: @Guillaume CreateNewList() is the forms.py. I have added the code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the context as a single argument inside a dictionary (and don't forget the parentheses in the query):

```py
    form = CreateNewList()
    empName = employeeName.objects.all()
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form":form, "empName":empName})
```

Also, if you want to override the form widget, it's better to do it [this way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```py
class CreateNewList(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```